# Uploading pictures to Google Drive using Fusion Tables

Tags: image, upload, google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

Is there any way to upload a picture to google drive within fusion tables, and then have the link for the image inserted in a cell in fusion tables?

I want to create a Fusion Table that includes people's names and pictures and other information about them. For example, I might have a row for "Bob" and his picture and information, and another row for "Tim" and his picture and information. Then I want to create separate views that could be shared with "Bob" and "Tim" so that they could edit their own information but not edit or see anyone else's. I know how to do that much. However, I want them to be able from within their view to upload a picture to google drive and have the link inserted in the spreadsheet. The point of this is that the picture is stored on google drive and can be viewed in a cell in the spreadsheet, and they can upload a picture without using a separate form. Is there any way to do this, or are there other options that could accomplish the same thing? Thanks!